# Why does Html.DisplayFor and .ToString("C2") not respect CurrentUICulture?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, globalization, azure-storage

In my ASP.MVC 2.0 website I have the following setting in web.config:

```
<globalization uiCulture="da-DK" culture="en-US" />
```

When I try to display an amount in a view using Html.DisplayFor() or ToString("C2") I expected to get "kr. 3.500,00" (uiCulture) and not "$3,500.00" (culture).

```
<%:Html.DisplayFor(posting => posting.Amount)%>
<%:Model.Amount.ToString("C2")%>
```

If I explicit uses CurrentUICulture info it works as expected, but I don't want to do that everytime I need to display a number, date or decimal. And I also like to use DisplayFor, which doesn't support the IFormatProvider parameter.

```
<%:Model.Amount.ToString("C2", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture)%>
```

How can I change the formatting, without changing the culture of the system?

This is running in Azure, and if I change the culture to "da-DK" all decimal points are lost, when saving to Azure Table storage! #BUG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UI culture is used to lookup and load resources, the Culture is used for formatting.

So the various `ToString(string)` and `String.Format` overloads that don't take a culture will use the thread's current Culture (`System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`) to format.

If you want to use Danish formatting for currency, dates, ... then `Thread.CurerentThread.CurrentCulture` needs to be set to `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("da-DK")` (directly or indirectly).

Summary: you have Culture and UI Culture the wrong way around.

Comment: Thanks... it turned out that my confusion is related to a "big" bug in Azure Developer Fabric. If regional settings are using comma as decimal point 1000,95 will get saved as 100095. Se: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/f327944c-e18a-490a-aa25-306f3c6a17de

Comment: @Thomas: if storing internally or transferring to another system (i.e. not for a user) then always use invariant culture or some other locale independent standard.